# Angular library - Can I import the components code?

Tags: angular, code-reuse, angular-library

I started to make my own components library for angular. the main reason is that I want to reuse components in future projects to be more productive and save time.

Now I can install my library in any new project and reuse my component.

for example :

```
<div>
  <ng-mylib-simple-spinner></ng-mylib-simple-spinner>
</div>
```

The problem is how I can handle more complex components?

What should  I do if  I need to get data from the users and pass it to service or another component? for example login-form component or if I want to reuse navbars and to change my `RouterLink` links etc.

How can I change the template and the logic for my library component in my new projects?
What should be my approach?

Comment: components that complex might not be great candidates to be part of libraries

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you need some templating adjustements (for example different layout for a menu) you could make use of `ContentChild` so that you would have a default template as well as option to override it

Comment: @bryan60 take an angular material. It's quite complex and it's a good candidate for a library.

Comment: @Sergey angular material doesn't provide login forms or really anything collecting information from a user besides form helpers and a few low level form components.  maybe "complex" isn't the right word, but things that "specific" aren't great candidates for libraries

Comment: @bryan60 have a look at CDK. It has tons of parameters. If it can be reused across projects then it has to be reused. For example I have a complex self-built library for working with tabs to share across projects. It consumes a lot of data to start, but it's easily reused and has an opportunity to override predefined template to implement some other tab layout. It all depend on situation

Comment: @bryan60 also there is an `ngrx` which is all about data. I agree about specificity, but if one make a library they shold be thinking about making it as abstract and general as possible

Comment: @Sergey nothing in the cdk or ngrx actually provides a form or anything interacting with an api layer.  it's all lower level and general. having a lot of parameters doesn't make something specifc. They both do very general things. this user is asking about specific forms or navs that are too app specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Issue is with Programming Principles instead of Programming Logic, I think. Let me explain:

Your reusable components should make it easier for you to develop a presentation layer. This means, styles, behavior, and everything else related to presentation, should be handled by the components, by knowing as little as possible from other components. This is called decoupling, and these components are usually called 'dumb components.'

The moment you want your reusable component to handle API requests and other things non-related to presentation, they are knowing too much. They are coupling and not providing their function: To reuse the presentation.

If you want to reuse logic, you create a service that is decoupled from presentation, and it should handle that particular's service logic. And then, you throw your dumb components into it to create a view, and you are saving time in the right way.

Remember: you want your components to know as little from one another as possible (so they are super reusable), and to do one thing and one thing only (presentation, auth, list-feature, table-component, modal-component), and then put them together like a weird Lego.

So, in short, you handle more complex components by creating them in 'smart components' which are nothing more than dumb components put together by the 'smart component' glue (which is the logic that makes sense for it).

Your paradigm to make a component be able to do it all, is the reason there are millions of libraries out there that you find to do one thing, but have to download 30Mb and put a million configuration options just to make it run. It's easier and simpler to just do it yourself. And to do it to apply for your product.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is actually make sense. Thanks alot

Comment: I chose wrong word and 'complex' it's not what I'm looking for. what I'm looking for is a way to import my 'dumb components' code, If there is a way to do it. in case I want to change them in new projects.

Comment: You mean component imports and exports?